# Disk.indices is higher than disk.used in cat allocation

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-indices

When I run the following command:

```
GET _cat/allocation?v&s=disk.indices&h=shards,disk.indices,disk.used,disk.available,disk.total,disk.percent
```

it shows the following output:

```
shards disk.indices disk.used disk.total disk.percent
   160        1.4tb     1.4tb      1.7tb           86
   160        1.4tb     1.4tb      1.7tb           87
   160        1.5tb     1.5tb      1.7tb           89
   160        1.5tb     1.5tb      1.7tb           90
   480        7.7tb     3.7tb       20tb           18
   480        7.7tb     3.9tb       20tb           19
```

Can anyone help me understand how come the `disk.indices` in last two rows **exceeds** `disk.used`?

Ideally the `disk.used` should be greater than or equal to `disk.indices`.

Comment: what is your version. can you share _cat/shards?

Comment: @hamidbayat Version is `7.10.2`. The output of `_cat/shards` is too huge. If there's a specific thing you want to look within it, let me know and I'll try to get it.